# How to detect a specific picture inside a video frame (or picture) using tensorflow.js

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflowjs

I've searched all over the place but could not find anything. I'm wondering if it is possible to find a specific image inside another image or video frame using tensorflow.js

Using OpenCV I can do it using feature detection but I'm wondering if something similar is possible using tensorflow.

[image]

Find the yellow card in the picture. But the card could also be a greeting card or a photo.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean one image inside another image? Is it "object detection"?

Comment: @stormzhou I’ve added an example image. I’m looking for the position of the yellow card in the picture.

Comment: It looks like it is indeed object detection task. Then yes, of course, it is possible. However, you need to to provide a lot of annotated images to train such a model.

Comment: @stormzhou could you point me to a tutorial or starting point, please.

Comment: A quick search gives me the following results: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection  https://medium.com/@WuStangDan/step-by-step-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-part-1-selecting-a-model-a02b6aabe39e

Comment: Yes, I found that. But how do I tell tensorflow that the object I'm looking for is the yellow card or a specific photo? I don't want it to detect people or kites? That is the part I'm struggling with.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you need to actually train a model to detect any specific object you want. And to do that, you need to manually label a lot of images to "teach" the model.

Comment: @stormzhou I might be completely off but the link you shared does use existing models. Where would I start to train my own model, as you mentioned? And how can I take care that the model works with tensorflowjs and preferably runs on a mobile browser?